# (4) Strip Comments | CodeWars Kata Training

Tags: python, strip

I wrote the code in PyCharm, and it worked perfectly. However, when I tried running it in the [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51c8e37cee245da6b40000bd) console, the output changed.

```
def strip_comments(strng, markers):
    strng = repr(strng)[1:-1]
    solution = strng
    substracted = 0
    for marker in markers:
        for i in range(len(strng)-1):
            if strng[i] == marker:
                if strng[i-1] == " ":
                    start = i-1
                else:
                    start = i

                while True:
                    try:
                        if f"{strng[i]}{strng[i+1]}" == r"\n":
                            solution = solution.replace(solution[start:i], "")
                            substracted += (i-start)
                            break
                    except IndexError:
                        return solution[:start-substracted]
                    i += 1

    return solution
```

The first test is to turn this (using the given markers: ['#', '!']):

- 'apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples'

to this:

- 'apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas'

In PyCharm my code works well, but in codewars console the output is:

- 'apples, pears\\ngrapes\\nbananas'

What am I missing? Please help me.

Comment: Those two outputs look the same

Comment: The problem is your use of `repr`.  You're returning the two characters `\n`, where as what they want is the single character newline, which is written as `\n` but contains neither a backslash nor an N.  Get rid of the `repr` and handle it as a normal string.  And you can use `splitlines` to handle things one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just handle one line at a time, and join them back up at the end.

```
def strip_comments(strng, markers):
    lines = []
    for line in strng.splitlines():
        for j in markers:
            i = line.find(j)
            if i >= 0:
                line = line[:i-1].rstrip()
        lines.append(line)
    return '\n'.join(lines)

print(strip_comments( 'apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples', '#!'))
```

Output:

```
apples, pears
grapes
bananas
```